# FirebaseでLINE認証するための方法？

Tags: ios, android, firebase

FirebaseでLINE認証をする方法をご教授頂きたいです。
Firebaseでは他のソーシャルアカウント（FacebookやTwitterのソーシャルログインはサポートしてますが、なぜかLINEだけは存在しません。

Firebaseでのアプリ開発において、LINE認証する場合どのような方法で
実現するのでしょうか？

単純なLINESDK(iOS,Android)を使った認証とFirebaseとの連携がわからず困っております。

ご教授のほど、宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 7, accepted):

サポートされていないプロバイダの認証を使ってFirebase認証をするにはカスタム認証システムを使用します。

- カスタム認証システムを追加する ([iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth?hl=ja), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth?hl=ja), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth?hl=ja))
- [カスタムトークンを作成する](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=ja)

実装方法としてはLINE SDKを使ってまずはLINEのアクセストークンを取得します。
取得したLINEのアクセストークンを使って自分が用意したサーバーへトークンを送ります。

サーバーで受け取ったLINEのアクセストークンの検証を行います。
検証用のAPIを叩くとmidを取得することができるので取得したmidをFirebaseのuidとしてFirebase SDKを使ってFirebaseのトークンを作成します。
作成したFirebaseのトークンはクライアントに返して、クライアントは受け取ったFirebaseのトークンを使ってログインするという流れになります。

GitHubに[サンプルコード](https://github.com/khanhlvg/custom-auth-samples/tree/8a47e411729a55060b544fde5ac23dc8e42d41b8/Line)があったのでそっちも参考にすると良いでしょう。